# Blazor concurrency conflict (same user, backend code)

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

we are evaluating Blazor as tech stack for a large enterprise application and I'm having some questions.

Let's say we have two text boxes and both can be edited by the user. When one edits the first one, a backend code is executed which might end in a code where the second text box (bind to property) is edited, one second after the first edit.
That can cause issues because the user might have typed in the second textbox in the meantime.

We might block user inputs while the backend code is running, however, I'd prefer to not block user inputs during server calculations.
Is there any good way of handling that?
The perfect solution would be that a popup appears because of concurrent edits, and the user can decide what to do. At least he is informed that his value might be overwritten.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The edit experience is what you code: yes you can achieve what you describe.  You need to consider the UX.  The user moves from your test box to another and is busy typing when a popup appears demanding his attention.  How does he return to where he was,...  In this case the two fields are linked so I would probably build a custom edit control that combined the two fields and provided a message if/when the backend result returned.

Comment: You have the same concurrency issue whatever framework you use for your application.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis not when you use a single threaded fw where leave fields are executed synchronously. But yeah, that's not js then.

Comment: A single thread doesn't equal synchronous.  The Blazor UI is inherently asynchronous, even when run on a single thread in WASM mode.

Comment: [Personal view] You should lock the input field until you're retrieved the value.  But I don't think you want to hear that so I'll sign off.  Is this really a major point in your  Blazor/Some Other Framework decision?

Comment: So what is the question? Whether it is better to disable input or show popup? That is out of scope for SO, I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

### Blazor Optional Input Value

Not sure this helps, but in Blazor Server you can do all kinds of creative combinations of what you describe.

One way to do this is the following: Instead of *binding* the first input to the second you just call a method and run your await-async server process that returns a new modified value based on the first input. The user can continue filling out the second input (or any input) as the *asynchronous* server Task is processing and it returns the new modified value.

When the await call to the server returns the new value, a *JSInteropt* call triggers a regular *JavaScript* `window.confirm(x)` popup with a question in the browser. They can choose to keep their value, clicking `"ok"`, or accept the one from the second input clicking `"cancel"`. Its not very sexy but it gives you an idea. Note: In this example below Im not modifying the first input from the server call, just passing the raw value to the second input.

You can paste the code below into any Blazor Server component and test it:

```
// Inject the JSInterop feature to use custom JavaScript in Blazor
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<input type="text" @onchange="MyMethod" /><br />
<input type="text" value="@MyValue" />

@code {
    private string? MyValue { get; set; } = "";
    private async Task MyMethod(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        // Add your await method call to the long-running
        // server process here.
        string newvalue = await GetNewServerValue(args);

        // Call a JavaScript window.confirm with a choice for the user
        string x = "Do you want to keep your own input?";
        bool result = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", x);

        // If the user does not want to keep what they typed,
        // they can click cancel in the confrim box and the first input
        // value replaces their own using the property below.
        if (!result) {
            //MyValue = newvalue;// use the servers modified value
            MyValue = args?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetNewServerValue(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        // I added a 5 second wait to simulate time for a user to enter
        // some text in the second input while waiting for the
        // server's response.
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        // Run your process and return your modified value...
        return "new value";
    }
}
```

I realize this is kinda sloppy. I'm not a fan of using JSInterop or JavaScript *prompts* like this. You run the danger of calling the JavaScript *global window object* outside of `SignalR` and dropping the *WebSocket* connection when you do these tricks or going over the Blazor Server SignalR **MaximumReceiveMessageSize** limit of **32k**. But Blazor gives you that creative ability to add all kinds of goodies like this.

**A better way of using a custom popup** would be to just build a new `Blazor Component in HTML with CSS` as a `<div>` and have that layer over your screen using `z-index in CSS`, then show and hide it based on the events above. Or this can be a tiny blazor component that slides into view beside the input with a choice they can quickly click.

But at least this shows you one of the many ways in Blazor to handle these kinds of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Two things: I only want to display a conflict dialogue if the user really did changes in the other text box which is in the meantime manipulated by the backend code. Second: my backend logic is triggered by the property change trigger of the entity, so in reality I'm not anymore in the blazor component, because I want that the code is independent to the ui, whenever I change the property value, it might alter another value (can be configured) and should raise errors in the ui if there is a conflict with the user (timing)

Comment: @Denny Weinberg Hope this helps. First Case: "I only want to display a conflict dialogue if the user really did changes in the other text box" - To handle that just use my code example and add If statement to check if "MyValue" is not empty. If so, that triggers the popup. Second Case: In your original post you said the first input changes the second. As long as thats the trigger, just use my async Tasks which allows your server to process while user types. Race conditions dont exist in Blazor using asynchronous events. Try Blazor IMemoryCache/delegates to trigger server delayed callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in one of the replies, the concurrency issues are the same irrespective of the framework. *However* the implementation can differ drastically depending on whether you use Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly.

1. **Blazor Server**: Since no code is executed at the client side, you can use Singleton DI to address concurrency issues (wherever needed). So a singleton service tracks the business object being modified against a user id (say 'x'). All other users are informed that user 'x' is modifying the item - similar to what you see in Google docs/sheets - very easily near real time.
2. **Blazor WebAssembly**: All code runs entirely in the browser. Unless explicitly informed via SignalR hub or otherwise, there is no way for two users to know what entity they are modifying.

Finally, you can always resolve concurrency optimistically (like EF Core). But keep in mind the fact that with WA, the concurrency conflict might become known  only at the point of commit - unless addressed explicitly.

Comment: We use blazor server. It's not about multi user. Please read my description carefully.

Comment: Then just show an autocomplete like drop down - users will ignore them if they want to. Then it is not a concurrency problem really - more of a UX problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The perfect solution would be that a popup appears because of
> concurrent edits, and the user can decide what to do. At least he is
> informed that his value might be overwritten.
>
> Any ideas?

So do exactly what you have described, where's the problem?

```
<input @bind="Model.PropertyA" @bind:after="OnPropertyAChanged" />
<input @bind="Model.PropertyB" />

@code 
{  
    async Task OnPropertyAChanged()
    {
         var propertyBBackup = Model.PropertyB;
         var propertyBNew = await _someService.CalculatePropertyBAsync(Model.PropertyA);
         if (propertyBNew != Model.PropertyB) //value changed by CalculateNewPropertyB
         {
              if (propertyBBackup != Model.PropertyB) //value changed by user
              {
                  var toast = await ToastService.Show(....);
                  toast.ClickedYes += 
                  {
                      Model.PropertyB = propertyBNew;                       
                  }
              }
         }
    }

}
```

If you are familiar with Reactive Extensions, I would build an operator (or extension method to detect changes to particular field while you are waiting for the source observable (`CalculatePropertyBAsync`) to emit a value and make this reusable. Something like:

```
_someService.CalculatePropertyBAsync(Model.PropertyA).ToObservable()
    .DetectConflict(() => Model.PropertyB, onConflict: LetUserDecideInDialog)
    .Subscribe(result => Model.PropertyB = result);
```

the advantage is, that you can combine this with `Switch/SelectMany` (better known as SwitchMap in RxJS) or `Throttle` operators to handle concurency issues when PropertyA changes too ofter and so on.